# Mysql select from table shifting one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which looks like this:

```
-----
| 1 |
-----
| 3 |
-----
| 7 |
-----
| . |
-----
| . |
-----
| . |
-----
| n |
-----
```

is it possible to select from this table to have something like this:

```
----------
| 1 || 3 |
----------
| 3 || 7 |
----------
| 7 || . |
----------
| . || . |
----------
| . || . |
----------
| n || n-1 |
```

Comment: Do you really want to **retrieve** the data like that, or just display it like that? What advantage does fetching the data as two spliced columns serve, other than slowing down the query?

Comment: yes I want to retrieve data like this.

Comment: OK. Why is there a need to do this?

Comment: If you *really* want to do this, don't do this using SQL, SQL is not about formatting the data. Do this in the front end application that you are using.

Comment: actually i have two columns one contain data like a1, a2, ...,an and second is like (a2)-1, (a3)-1, ..., (an)-1, (some value). and this table contains a lot of records, and also this table have index on the first column but not on second. so I want to retrieve second column by shifting first. Because if I would select * from this table it would take up to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, below query is nearest what you want with MySQL

```
mysql> select * from num;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    7 |
|   11 |
|   17 |
+------+

mysql> select @prev:=a FROM num ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1,1;
+----------+
| @prev:=a |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @prev, t1.a, @prev:=t1.a from num t1;
+-------+------+-------------+
| @prev | a    | @prev:=t1.a |
+-------+------+-------------+
|     3 |    1 |           1 |  <= 1st row is dummy
|     1 |    3 |           3 |
|     3 |    7 |           7 |
|     7 |   11 |          11 |
|    11 |   17 |          17 |
+-------+------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select MAX(a), NULL FROM num;
+--------+------+
| MAX(a) | NULL |
+--------+------+
|     17 | NULL | <= last row founded here
+--------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Relational data has no concept of row-numbers or row-ordering, so "shifting by 1 row" is not possible using (standard) SQL. If your table contains a  field "rownumber" you could use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.field, t2.field
  FROM mytable t1 join mytable t2 on(t1.rownumber = t2.rownumber+1)
```

But as BenM stated: just shifting by one row doesn't make too mauch sense, but if you have any other join-criteria a self-join is a useful tool.

Comment: this table doesnt contain any id

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already marked. But I am posting it here for other user.

```
DECLARE @mytable table
(
    mycolumn varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @mytable 
SELECT '| 1 |' UNION ALL
-----
SELECT '| 3 |' UNION ALL
-----
SELECT '| 7 |' UNION ALL
----- 
SELECT '| . |' UNION ALL
-----
SELECT '| . |' UNION ALL
-----
SELECT '| . |' UNION ALL
-----
SELECT '| n |'

SELECT * FROM @mytable 

SELECT 
    t1.mycolumn, t2.mycolumn
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn) as rownum, mycolumn
    from @mytable
) t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn)as rownum, mycolumn
    from @mytable
) t2 
on(t1.rownum = t2.rownum+1)
WHERE t2.rownum > 0
```

This query is for sql server.

Look at the following part that basically have the logic

```
SELECT 
    t1.mycolumn, t2.mycolumn
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn) as rownum, mycolumn
    from @mytable
) t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn)as rownum, mycolumn
    from @mytable
) t2 
on(t1.rownum = t2.rownum+1)
WHERE t2.rownum > 0
```